# FileStream.ReadByte - Inefficient - What is the meaning of this?

Tags: .net, performance, filestream

> > The default implementation on Stream creates a new single-byte array and then calls Read. While this is formally correct, it is inefficient. Any stream with an internal buffer should override this method and provide a much more efficient version that reads the buffer directly, avoiding the extra array allocation on every call.

Taken from the FileStream.ReadByte documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.readbyte.aspx

What is the meaing of this and how do I overcome this inefficiency?

Comment: Determine the meaning of the above quote such that I can make reasonable decisions based on said meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only of concern when you inherit from `Stream`. When doing so, you must provide at least a `Read` method, `ReadByte` is implemented on top of it in the base class. This is fine, but inefficient when your stream is capable of getting individual bytes directly - the default implementation would then first create a single-byte buffer internally, pass it to `ReadByte` to fill it, and then return the single byte. If you can implement your buffer so that the single byte can be returned directly, without allocating a temporary buffer, you should do so.

For the calling code, the only consideration is that when you need to read bytes just to store them in a buffer, `Read` is often more efficient than `ReadByte`, even when you're only reading a single byte - but if you really only need one byte, and the stream implementation you're using provides an optimized version, `ReadByte` may actually be faster. If you read individual bytes for immediate processing, `ReadByte` shouldn't be a problem at all - after all, most of the standard stream classes are buffered already and should provide an optimized `ReadByte`. If in doubt, profile.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the meaning seems reasonably clear - and the workaround is simply not to call `ReadByte`.

Don't read one byte at a time - read into a buffer of an appropriate size (I usually go for about 8K, but anything of around that order of magnitude should be fine) using the [`Read(byte[], int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) method. If you need to read bytes individually after that, read them one at a time from the buffer.

This becomes a problem if you need to make sure you don't read more than you're meant to, if you see what I mean - if you're not meant to read past the first 0 byte, for example, because that means it's the start of the next "message" and you want to be able to read again later. Ideally, avoid designing yourself into that sort of situation.

Wrapping a `FileStream` in a `BufferedStream` *may* help in that case, but I would measure the performance carefully if it's important... and still try to avoid designs which require reading a single byte at a time if you can help it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Read` method to read to a buffer. Reading single byte is not efficient. Using buffer:

```
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // 4K
  int bytesRead =0;
  while((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))>0)
  {
  // Do whatever with buffer
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem in using `FileStream`'s `ReadByte()` method.

I think the documentation is actually confusing.

The `ReadByte()` method implemented by the abstract [Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) class is inefficient because it "creates a new single-byte array and then calls `Read()`".

However, the overridden version of `ReadByte()` implemented by [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) heeds the advice of this warning by reading the internal buffer directly as you can see in the source [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,1e830b91f42c8c20,references). So it isn't clear why the documentation for `FileStream`'s `ReadByte()` holds on to this warning.

Comment: +1 the latest source for `ReadByte()` in .NET 5 is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/04b6c41b64a4090c1a83a48e66902235dd33e7f6/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/BufferedFileStreamStrategy.cs#L275) and the function just indexes into the internal array buffer which is a fast operation if you haven't consumed the entire buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I would read that as a very poorly written way to say "don't use the ReadByte() and use [Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) instead".  Particularly since the documentation for Read() says

> This method overrides Read.

in the Remarks section.